# SU into other user, but can't use LS

Tags: directory, permissions, command-line-interface, ls, su

raf@XPS15:~$ su Jose
$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

Why can't I do it?

I can add Jose to the sudo group and use sudo ls, but not regular ls. Why and how can I fix this?µ

I'm running Ubuntu on a VM in Oracle Virtualbox if that helps.